# Extra Space with a joined filed using Scanner and SequenceInputStream

Tags: java, file, inputstream, java.util.scanner, printwriter

OK, here is the content of first file heavy1.rtf:

```
>  hello, this  
>is 
>a 
> ?new EJava program
>  
>         C:\ heavy1.rtf                  500
```

here is the content of first file heavy2:

```
>first line 
>2nd line 
>more line 
>enough is enough 
>eNd
```

heavy1 and heavy2 were created using another java program. heavy3 was hand made and looks like this:

```
> fsd 
>fd 
>sdf 
>sdfsd
```

then I ran this code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class newfile3
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int x=500;
File f1 = new File("C:/ heavy1.rtf");//file already exists
File f2 = new File("C:/ heavy2.rtf");//file already exists
File f3 = new File("C:/heavy3.rtf");//file already exists
File f4 = new File("C:/ heavymerge.rtf");//does not exist
try
{
FileInputStream str1 = new FileInputStream(f1);
FileInputStream str2 = new FileInputStream(f2);
FileInputStream str3 = new FileInputStream(f3);
SequenceInputStream qstr = new SequenceInputStream(new SequenceInputStream(str1,str2),str3);

Scanner sc = new Scanner(qstr);

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f4);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
pw.println(sc.nextLine());
}
qstr.close();
pw.close();
sc.close();
sc = new Scanner(f4);
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}

sc.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){}

}    

}
```

So it does read from the 3 files and merge them in heavymerge.rtf. The problem is that there is an extra space before first line.like

```
  first line
2nd line
```

Also, heavy 3 is merged in bizzarre way. 
It starts with

> {\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl ...etc

and prints the main content like

```
sdf\par
sdfsd\par
}
```

...

Is there a way I can stop these extra spaces and be more precise.
Are there other options for chaining and joining other than SequenceInputStream?
What if I want erase portions of the file? There doesn't seem to be any backspace.

Comment: Are you really trying to "merge" (which isn't the right word) RTF files - files in Microsoft's Rich Text Format? I suggest that you use WordPad to create a simple text file with file type .txt and play with that.

Comment: You might also want to investigate your .rtf files with a text editor that can reveal special characters (such as CR, LF, etc.) and double check the encoding of the files to make sure they're all the same.

Comment: @laune  I tried to do with with .txt as well. Still the space is there.

Comment: The spaces in front of "first line", which is in the second file, can be due to a trailing line without line end (CR+LF) in the first file. Happens when you edit, leave spaces in the last line but don't hit enter.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But can you tell me how I can delete potions of the file, or may be use backspace?

Comment: @thomas88p Can you give example of text editors I should use?

Comment: @loin. I know that I can erase the whole file using g.close() and then writing again, but I want to delete portions of the file.